# Tweepy to only reply to new mentions and ignore the ones that i've already replied to

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm making a twitter bot that replies to `@ mentions` with graphs containing the average sentiment of their 100 most recent tweets and retweets. The problem I'm having is the bot will reply to posts that it's already replied to. If anyone could help me skip users who I've already responded I'd very much appreciate it!

Any help is appreciated!

[This](https://github.com/JoshAlvarado/Tweepy-Reply-/blob/master/TweepyReply_.ipynb) is what I have right now.